# Heroku + Node.js + Peer.js (webrtc): Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, peerjs

I can't to connect from client script:

```
this.Peer = new Peer({host: PEER_SERVER_ADDR, 
port: PEER_PORT_ADDR, //at this context: 30028
path: PEER_PATH_ADDR,
debug: true,
config:{'iceServers'[{urls:'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}  ]}
});
```

to peer signal server:

```
var express = require("express");
var ExpressPeerServer = require("peer").ExpressPeerServer;
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
//var BodyParser = require("body-parser"); 

var const_and_funcs = require("./vk_space_chat_constants_and_general_functions.js");
var app = express();
var heroku_port = process.env.PORT || const_and_funcs.PEER_PORT_ADDR; //:30028
var server = app.listen(heroku_port);
console.log(heroku_port);
console.log(const_and_funcs.PEER_PATH_ADDR + " ");

var options = {
    debug: true
};

var peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, options);
app.use(const_and_funcs.PEER_PATH_ADDR, peerServer);
app.use(jsonParser);
app.use(urlencodedParser);
```

But when I'm trying to connect to server, I have this problem:

```
h t t p s :// My_App.herokuapp.com:30028/vk_space_chat/peerjs/id?ts=14850577089420.5386418990500108 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  ERROR Error retrieving ID undefined
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  ERROR Aborting!
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  ERROR Error: Could not get an ID from the server.
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  ERROR Error retrieving ID ProgressEvent
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  ERROR Aborting!
peer.min.js:1 PeerJS:  ERROR Error: Could not get an ID from the server.
```

But the same code works at my local Node.js server!!! Without problems!
Can anyone help me?.. 
Maybe there is a problem with WebSockets?..
Or maybe that will be better to use normal VPS?

Comment: were you able to get through the firewall and achieve a successful connection? If so what procedure did you follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite likely that the port is not open - your local firewall/router may be blocking it, or your server's firewall may be blocking it.

To test this out, just use a web browser to access the peerjs server address (including the port number), and if it's open, you'll get a simple message back. If not, it may timeout or give you some other error message - meaning it is blocked

Comment: alright, I did that! And it seems that port is blocked... I tried to open in browser https://my_app_name.herokuapp.com:43545 (43545 = process.env.PORT, and got ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Chrome!

Comment: ok, so your next step is to work out where it's getting blocked

Comment: To build onto Mikkel's answer... I'm facing this same issue. I believe it's because of Heroku's firewall. They only let you work through certain ports.

Comment: The ports they provide in the env should be unblocked right? I am not sure why the issue should arise then. I have a similar issue. Any tips?